# Postgis database spatial_ref_sys table not found

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm working with a big OSM database and it seems that the postgis spatial_ref_sys table get corrupted after I moved tablespace. The database looks like this:

```
                              Liste des relations
 Schéma |              Nom              | Type  | Propriétaire | Taille  | Description 
--------+-------------------------------+-------+--------------+---------+-------------
 public | osm_admin                     | table | osm          | 4504 MB | 
 public | osm_aeroways                  | table | osm          | 42 MB   | 
 public | osm_amenities                 | table | osm          | 110 MB  | 
 public | osm_barrierpoints             | table | osm          | 251 MB  | 
 public | osm_barrierways               | table | osm          | 1343 MB | 
 public | osm_buildings                 | table | osm          | 71 GB   | 
 public | osm_housenumbers              | table | osm          | 5317 MB | 
 public | osm_housenumbers_interpolated | table | osm          | 305 MB  | 
 public | osm_landusages                | table | osm          | 29 GB   | 
 public | osm_landusages_gen0           | table | osm          | 1658 MB | 
 public | osm_landusages_gen1           | table | osm          | 5477 MB | 
 public | osm_places                    | table | osm          | 440 MB  | 
 public | osm_roads                     | table | osm          | 44 GB   | 
 public | osm_roads_gen0                | table | osm          | 2521 MB | 
 public | osm_roads_gen1                | table | osm          | 2775 MB | 
 public | osm_transport_areas           | table | osm          | 54 MB   | 
 public | osm_transport_points          | table | osm          | 545 MB  | 
 public | osm_waterareas                | table | osm          | 8217 MB | 
 public | osm_waterareas_gen0           | table | osm          | 329 MB  | 
 public | osm_waterareas_gen1           | table | osm          | 1028 MB | 
 public | osm_waterways                 | table | osm          | 9284 MB | 
 public | osm_waterways_gen0            | table | osm          | 1813 MB | 
 public | osm_waterways_gen1            | table | osm          | 2514 MB | 
 public | spatial_ref_sys               | table | postgres     | 0 bytes | 
(24 lignes)
```

The spatial_ref_sys table is 0 bytes and when I try to read it, I get:

```
ERROR: could not open the file « pg_tblspc/18537/PG_12_201909212/6968974/6969280 » : no file
```

Is there a way I could replace this table ? I've tried to drop the postgis extension but I would have to do a DROP CASCADE which would drop all the related osm tables ...
Any idea ?
Thanks

PS: I'm using postgresql 12 and postgis 3.0

Comment: Have you tried to populate this table manually? `psql -d yourdb -f /usr/share/postgresql/12/contrib/postgis-3.0/spatial_ref_sys.sql`

Comment: yes i've tried and I get the same error ... missing file in my tablespace

Comment: that's odd. haven't you installed it first in your OS? what happens if you try `sudo apt-get install postgresql-12-postgis-3`? after that the file might be there - here I'm assuming you're using ubuntu. You might wanna check where the files are copied after installation if you're using a different OS.

Comment: so I finally created a new db with postgis extension then I've checked the spatial_ref_sys file using pg_relation_filepath and copied the file in my initial db tablespace with name 6969280 ... it worked, the spatial_ref_sys table is not empty anymore, but stil when trying to access it, I get permission denied ...

Comment: You mean the current user cannot access the spatial_ref_sys table? Who is the owner of this table in your database?

Comment: db owner is 'osm' (not superuser) and spatial_ref_sys owner is postgres (superuser) ... but I get permission denied even when I connect as postgres

Comment: Error : could not open file  « pg_tblspc/18537/PG_12_201909212/6968974/6969280 » : permission denied

Comment: fixed ... chown postgres:postgres to file 6969280 in my tablespace